# How to load and use chartist plugins when using retyped mappings?

Tags: .net, chartist.js, bridge.net

I'm using the retyped.chartist lib for .NET (you can find the nugget in the VS extension browser) and you probably know it's syntax is a bit unconventional. I was wondering if anyone knows how to add plugins there? I can see they have a plugins variable but it's es5.Array which is a really broad definition with no documentation.

P.S. I can't tag retyped because I don't have enough reputation.

Answer (score -2):

Chartist has nothing to do with the server. It is to be used only on the client side. Just include its js source in the webpage you use and 'print out' the setting and data. Settings are given by your needs and data is dynamically generated by the server. I do not know bridge.net, neither .net, but chartist is for the browser.

Comment: Um... my frontend is also .Net and I'm using bridge.Net in order to translate it to JS. Retyped.chartist provides a C# mapping to the js lib so I can write C# code for my charts. Most of the chartist plugins are js only as it appears and I can't figure out if there's a way to use these plugins with my retyped.chartist lib. Your answer will not be accepted since it's not helpful, sorry.